# Notifications on Stack. When should I create a new question instead of adding on to an existing one, particularly an older question?

Tags: discussion, comments, asking-questions

I have this problem all the time on SO.  Let's say I have a question about **foo**, and I find a similar existing question.  In the comments some alternate approaches are discussed.  I would like to ask a question related to one of those comments.

I would like to post a comment instead of asking a new question for conciseness but I'm concerned that my activity will go unnoticed, whereas new questions always get noticed.  Would a new comment receive the same level of visibility?

Somewhat related, are there @ notifications on Stack?  I see people do this all the time in comments, where they direct a question to a user.  But do they receive a notification?

Comment: See [How do @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/307988)

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to post a comment instead of asking a new question for
>   conciseness

I do not think conciseness should figure into this decision.

Questions are for asking questions.  You can always link back to any comment(s) that led to them, if you need to.

Comments are intended only for clarifying questions (and answers).

If you have a question of any importance at all about a comment, then I would recommend that you ask a question in the area reserved for questions rather than risking it being overlooked in a comment trail.